# How to hide server response header of NGINX from Angular frontend using docker file?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, http-headers, alpine-linux

I need to hide the 'server' response header from the response headers of my project, I am using NGINX
and the server header is coming as nginx/1.23.4,

I need to hide it from Angular Frontend using the Dockerfile in it
I am using Docker Alpine Image to deploy.
[Response Headers ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEH0E.png)

I tried with **server_tokens off;** & **proxy_hide_header server;**
in nginx config file and copying it to the server from **dockerfile** in my angular project folder
by adding this command in dockerfile,
**COPY /nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

I also tried using the **more_clear_headers Server;** but this also didn't work for me.

This is the code for NGINX deployment in my Dockerfile,
[NGINX Deployment through Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0kV7.png)

Comment: Please have a look at [ask], especially the part reading _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** — copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)"_.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you find answer to this? I have exact same query and I cannot hide 'Server' header. Although I can hide nginx version using `server_tokens off;`