# How to hide 'Server' header from web frontend on NGINX ALPINE using Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, http-headers, alpine-linux

Extending the following post [How to hide server response header of NGINX from Angular frontend using docker file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76001822/7109362)

Adding my code what I have tried and what outcome I got.

1. I used `server_tokens off;` inside `http {...}` block

   ***Dockerfile***

   ```docker
    FROM nginx:1.24.0-alpine

    # Copy custom configuration like 'server_tokens off;' in nginx.conf
    COPY ngx.cust.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

    # Copy the built Angular app files into the Nginx web server directory
    COPY dist/my-angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html

    # Expose port 80 to the outside world
    /EXPOSE 80

    # Start Nginx when the container starts
    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
   ```

   ***ngx.cust.conf*** (to be copied into /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

   ```nginx
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

    ...


    http {
        ...

        # Hide nginx headers
        server_tokens off;

        ...
    }
   ```

   This hides the version number of nginx but not the complete 'Server' header

---

2. I tried another param `add_header Server '';` with empty value in **nginx.conf** to replace existing value

but it added another `Server` header alongwith old one

---

3. I added one more param set `proxy_set_header Server 'unknown';` and `proxy_hide_header Original-Header;` in **nginx.conf**

but it didn't show any outcome on header

---

4. I used another param `more_clear_headers Server;` in **nginx.conf**

   ```nginx
    # Hide nginx headers
    server_tokens off;
    more_clear_headers Server;
   ```

   but it said `unknown directive "more_clear_headers"`
   [image: unknown directives]

   I found that this require `nginx-extras` binary but it is not available in alpine so I added `nginx-mod-http-headers-more` binary in ***Dockerfile***

   ```docker
    RUN apk update && apk add nginx-mod-http-headers-more
   ```

   and loaded module in **nginx.conf**

   ```nginx
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

    # Loaded installed module
    load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

    ...


    http {
        ...
        more_clear_headers Server;
    }
   ```

   but this thrown me version error for binary
   [image: nginx alpine version issue]

   So I explicitly gave version number with binary installation in ***Dockerfile***

   ```docker
    RUN apk update && apk add nginx-mod-http-headers-more=1.24.0-r7
   ```

   But still got error
   [image: nginx alpine compatibility issue]

---

5. Then I try to use multiple versions of nginx for downloading binary and then main use.

   First I changed ***Dockerfile*** to use later version of the nginx to download binary and then in main (under older version), copy that downloaded binary

   ```docker
    FROM nginx:1.25.3-alpine-slim AS builder

    RUN apk update && apk add nginx-mod-http-headers-more

    # Use an official Nginx image as the base image
    FROM nginx:1.24.0-alpine

    # Copy the already downloaded binary from builder
    COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so
   ```

   I got the obvious error of binary compatibility
   [image: nginx binary uncompatible]

---

What binary or technique should be used here to achieve hiding complete server info from headers?

Comment: Looks like what you're looking for is https://serverfault.com/a/1005325

Comment: this suggested the `nginx-extras` module via `apt install` (debian command) and I want alpine one (using `apk add` command)